# How to use less than or equal to a value of a column as a condition to select the row in another column?

Tags: r, operators, data-manipulation

Simple question, I think. Basically, I want to use the concept "less than or equal to a number" as the condition to select the row of one column, and then find the value on the same row in another column. But what happens if the number stated in the condition isn't found in the first column?

Let's assume this is my data frame:

```
df<-as.data.frame((matrix(c(1:10,11:20), nrow = 10, ncol = 2)))
df
   V1 V2
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   5 15
6   6 16
7   7 17
8   8 18
9   9 19
10 10 20
```

Let's assume I want to use the condition `<=5` in df$V1 to obtain the row that is used to find the value of the same row in df$V2.

```
df[which(df$V1 <= 5),2]
15
```

But what happens if the number used in the condition isn't found? Let's assume this is my new data.frame

```
   V1 V2
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   6 15
6   7 16
7   8 17
8   9 18
9  10 19
10 11 20
```

Using the same above command `df[which(df$V1 <= 5),2]`, I obtain a different answer. For some reason I obtain the entire column instead of one number.

```
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea where are you getting these results from. In both your old and new data sets you are supposed to get several values as a result. In the first case the output I'm getting is `[1] 11 12 13 14 15`, while in the second case I'm getting `[1] 11 12 13 14`. Both make perfect sense. What are you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

Use the subset operator:

```
df[df[,2]<= 5,1]
```

Comment: In particular, this answer uses a logical subsetting vector for the rows rather than a numeric subsetting vector. In the case you have, an all `FALSE` vector selects nothing where an empty numeric vector selects everything.